# Compute the Nth float

Tags: java, c++, c

With 32 bit floats I think there is something like 2^31 - 1 representable floats. In java you can take an existing float and find the "next float" using the Math library. But lets say you don't have a starting float, is there a way to compute the nth float? I don't care what language, if there is a language with a library function I'll take it.

Of course I could simply put all the floats in an array and index into that, but that is space inefficient.

Here is some further clarification. I could start at Float.MIN and increment N times using nextFloat, but this seems inefficient because I need to perform this operation many times.

Comment: in Java, start at Float.MIN_VALUE.

Comment: Do they have to be in order? ie. float n+1 > float n. It's not you just want to map [0..2^31) to floats?

Comment: @CarlManaster That works but you have to loop N times to get the answer... I'm trying to think of a way to connect N to the binary representation but I don't think you can. Perhaps that is the best answer.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  At any rate, I imagine in C/C++, reinterpreting the bits of an integer as a float is probably the best path...

Comment: So, if you don't care what language it is, why don't you use Java's `nextUp` or whatever you're referring to? Neither C nor C++ provides any such *standard* function. You will have to roll your own.

Comment: The floats can have an order, but it doesn't matter I just need a map of them all and the ability to index into it O(1). But I don't want to store all the floats in an array. I need a expression for the Nth float or some computational way of getting at it.

Comment: I can't use nextFloat because I want something close to O(1) access to a random float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on how you want them ordered. Keep in mind that not all floats are ordered at all; for instance, a pair of distinct NaNs are unordered (i.e, they are not equal, but neither one is greater than the other).

If you don't mind ending up with those, you can just reinterpret an integer as a float. The way you'd do this varies from language to language; here's a C implementation:

```
float int_to_float(uint32_t in) {
    union {
        float f;
        uint32_t i;
    } u;

    u.i = in;
    return u.f;
}
```

This has the convenient property of giving you mostly ordered results -- passing in zero gets you 0.0, one gets you 1.4e-45, 2 gets you 2.8e-45, and so on. The results will start getting crazy once you get into NaN/Inf values, and will eventually start *decreasing* once you hit 0x80000000 (-0.0), but that should be good enough for now.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the NaN condition? from the bits of the float? Or will this method always give a float value?

Comment: When a number is NaN, the exponent bits are set to 0xFF (for single precision floats).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: So, you would have to increment a *long* time to hit NaN; the hex pattern of your float would be 0x7F800000, or over two billion as an integer.

Comment: Well, I think the infinities also have `0xFF` exponent bits, but they're not technically NaNs...

Comment: Correct. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding -- infinity is FF exponent with zero mantissa, all other mantissas are NaN.